# In Excel, how do I check if any cell in a given range is invalid according to its data validation rules?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

In Excel, I am trying to write a formula that checks whether any cell in certain range of cells contains invalid data, according to each cell's data validation rules. I want to use this information to display a message in a cell near the top of the sheet, so the user doesn't have to scroll through the whole sheet to see if it contains any invalid data.

All the cells in the range I want to check use the same rules for their data validation, but these rules are fairly complex and are dependent on the values of other cells in each row. I already know that you can check whether any cell in a given column equals a certain value using the VLOOKUP Function, (E.g. `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP("Lookup Value", A1:A20, 1, FALSE)), "Not Found", "Found")`), but there doesn't seem to be any way to use that same method to check for cells with invalid data.

Is there a way to do this in Excel without using VBA? If not, can you recommend an alternative solution?

Comment: I don't believe you can use a simple formula to directly reference the validation of a cell but you could use a formula similar to the condition used in the data validation, what's the rule? Doesn't the validation prevent entry of invalid data....or is it pasted in?

Comment: @barryhoudini Well, here's a formula that I put in cell E16 which returns true when that cell is invalid: `=AND(OR(D16="Fail", D16="N/A"), LEN(E16) <= 0)`. (This formula is taken from my conditional formatting, it highlights invalid fields in red.)

Comment: @barryhoudini The validation doesn't prevent invalid data from being entered because the validation itself is conditional upon the value of an adjacent cell. E.g. In the example above, E16 is only invalid if its length is 0 AND the value of D16 is "Fail" or "N/A".

So E16 might be valid, and then the value of D16 might change and suddenly make it invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So any row is invalid if it contains Fail or N/A in column D and column E in the same row is blank?

Try using COUNTIFS to see if there are any invalid rows, e.g. this formula at the top

`=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(D:D,{"Fail","N/A"},E:E,"")),"Invalid Data","All OK")`

or this version will give you the number of instances

`=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(D:D,{"Fail","N/A"},E:E,"")),SUM(COUNTIFS(D:D,{"Fail","N/A"},E:E,""))&" Row(s) of Invalid Data","All OK")`

COUNTIFS is only valid in Excel 2007 or later, in earlier versions you can count invalid rows with SUMPRODUCT, i.e.

`=SUMPRODUCT((D1:D1000={"Fail","N/A"})*(E1:E1000=""))`

Comment: So I looked into the COUNTIFS function and it seems really useful. I am a bit curious though as to why the SUM function is needed in your example. Why doesn't COUNTIFS give the correct number of invalid rows on its own? =/

Comment: In this formula `=COUNTIFS(D:D,{"Fail","N/A"},E:E,"")`, because one of the criteria is an "array", i.e. `{"Fail","N/A"}` then the `COUNTIFS` also returns an array of two value (one the count of all rows with "Fail" and blank, one the count of all rows with "N/A" and blank) and SUM is required to add the 2 values. You could use 2 separate `COUNTIFS` functions but this is a little shorter....